# Sql Server: keep autoincrement from resetting when table is truncated

Tags: sql, sql-server, identity, unique-key

This question is basically the inverse from some other questions that have been asked.

I have a table with an incrementing identity, defined as follows:

```
[Instance_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL
```

This works fine. However, when I remove all records from this table and start inserting new ones, `Instance_ID` starts over from 1. This is causing quite some problems when I take extracts from this table for later use.

Is there a way to make sure that this particular column will **never** generate the same value twice, even after being truncated?

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: better to set starting identity value which is greater than last inserted rows for that table.

Comment: Starting 2012 MSSS has SEQUENCE.

Comment: There are solutions/workaround to miss your question. BUT you should rethink what you are doing. if you need really no duplicates have a look at other things xuch as SEQUENCES as stated by Serg.

Answer (score 1):

You can save current ident and use it when reseeding:

```
DECLARE @i INT = IDENT_CURRENT('tablename') + 1
TRUNCATE TABLE tablename
DBCC CHECKIDENT(tablename, RESEED, @i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Delete Table without where clause instead of truncating the table.

Try like this.

```
Delete tablename
```

Comment: Would be much slower than truncating the table.

Comment: You should get the last incremented value then truncate the table and then reseed the table with that value. This process involves DDL as well. We can simply delete the table

Answer (score 0):

Reseed your table

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT (yourtable, reseed, 154)
```

Instead of 154 use the value from which you want the Instance_ID

Comment: in this case you have to do 3 steps. 1. save old max value, 2. truncate, reset id. Better have a look at sequences and move from autoincrement to manual increment.

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @id int
Select @id = max(id)+1 from testtable
Truncate Table testtable
Dbcc CheckIdent (testtable, reseed, @id)
```